# After upgrading an EE1 site to EE2, should you delete any unused database tables?

Tags: database, ee2-upgrades

For example, exp_weblog_ or exp_trackbacks?  Any others? Is this something that you normally do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that this was happening because I was importing the database from a dev server, into the production server database, without first dropping all tables...which left unused/old tables still in the production database.

Answer (score 2):

I would've thought that any exp_weblog_ tables should automatically get converted to exp_channel_ so if they're still there, that would raise a red-flag with me.

Same with exp_trackbacks; if you've selected not to keep them during the upgrade process, then that table should be removed.

The only tables that should be left over would be ones that were added by older add-ons that you're not using anymore.

Comment: exp_weblog always seems to be left for me, even though the conversion to exp_channel worked perfect.  I assume it's there in case we need a backup of the old table for some reason.

Comment: Same for me too Jon. I've checked a few sites that we've upgraded to EE2 and they still have those tables and the sites work perfectly.

Comment: Just checked back through all the EE1->EE2 upgrades I did last year and none of them had any exp_weblog tables left over.

Comment: I wonder if it was an issue with certain builds. I'll need to check into other sites that we've upgraded and compare.